# How to trigger an event on change of value of a variable in typescript - nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, events

I have a project in typescript which perform some job.

```
export class Job {
  public jobState: 'Active' | 'Completed' | 'Paused' | 'Cancelled';
  public jobId: string;
}
```

I have a map object which is a list of active jobs,

```
private static jobStreams: Map<string, Job> = new Map();
```

In my code, I need to be informed when the state of the job changes, like when the user chooses to 'Pause' the job ,

the corresponding map object state is set to 'Paused' like this,

```
jobStreams.set(job.jobId).jobState = 'Paused';
```

I want to lnow how to trigger an event when the state of a job changes?

I will be doing some activities on the job and when the job is paused, I should be able to get an event that intimates me of a job state change, so that I can stop all the processing.

Is there some event handling mechanism available in Typescript and nodejs which I can use for my use case?

Right now I am using a polling mechanism using setTimeout to check for job state change, which is not ideal.

Comment: Use a proxy or create a wrapper class/object that manages the Map and calls event handlers when needed.

Comment: Any example on how to use a proxy in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can either trigger an event manually by extending `EventEmitter` and emitting an event whenever you set the value:

```
setJob(job) {
  jobStreams.set(job.jobId).jobState = 'Paused';
  this.emit('job-paused', job);
}
```

Or use a reactivity system like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) for observing state and reactivity change.

While a reactivity system is easier in practice you're going to need to publish the state change and subscribe to it across servers (what if you have more than one instance).

This is typically done via a message broker (like Kafka) or a pub-sub system like [Redis pub-sub](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

Comment: Any examples on EventEmitter ?